# VBA - Auto format wrapped cells so the width of the cell is equal to the width of the longest word

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to set the width of each column so that no individual word in the wrapped text cell is split into 2 lines. Excel handle this for words less wide than the width of the column. However, words that are wider than the column are split. I would like the column to auto format the width so that it would be just wide enough so the longest word would not need to be split. Does Excel have a way to handle this?

Comment: yeah, you can do something like Columns("A:E").AutoFit

Comment: Thanks, however when using wrapped text AutoFit will split the longer words if the column width is too thin.

Comment: you can't use wrap text with .Autofit

Comment: Did the macro below end up working for you?

Comment: Yes, for the most part. It is not a perfect solution as I have found cases where it doesn't work and obviously will only work for some fonts and sizes. However, it is still helpful in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty good approximation.  It sizes the column to be a little bit wider than the longest word.  So the cell won't be the exact same width as the longest word, it will be a little bit wider, but it stops the longest word from getting split.

The sub foo is an example of sizing the column to the largest word in cell A1 on Sheet1.  You can add another function to check all of the cells in the column to get the longest word in the column.  Right now we are just checking for the longest word in one cell within the column.

```
Option Explicit

Sub foo()

    FitColToLongestWord Sheet1.Range("A1")

End Sub

Sub FitColToLongestWord(cell As Range)

    Dim strLongestWordLen   As String
    Dim str()               As String
    Dim LongestWordLength   As Integer

    str() = Split(cell.Value, " ")
    LongestWordLength = GetLongestWordLength(str())
    Sheet1.Columns(cell.Column).ColumnWidth = LongestWordLength

End Sub

Function GetLongestWordLength(str() As String) As Integer

    Dim i       As Integer
    Dim max     As Integer
    Dim current As Long

    max = Len(str(LBound(str)))
    For i = LBound(str) To UBound(str)
        current = Len(str(i))
        If current > max Then
            max = current
        End If
    Next i

    GetLongestWordLength = max

End Function
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that code will only set the `ColumnWidth` to be the number of characters in the longest word.  But the `ColumnWidth` of the column required to fit a word depends on what font type and size (etc) is being used, not just how many characters are in the word.

Comment: Agreed.  As I said, it's an approximation which is why the cell width is coming out a little bit longer than the longest word.  The word length used to determine the column width could be adjusted if it becomes too short based on font.  In my case, it was actually making the cell width a little bit wider than needed.  I think this is a good solution for most applications.

Comment: Thanks! I have found a few words that are still too wide, and thus are split over two lines. However, most of the time this solution works well for me.